# angular service returning twice

Tags: angular, routes, jwt

I am trying to implement a RoleGuardService on my angular project. I have a route guarded where user is required to have a specific role.

```
export class RoleGuardService implements CanActivate {

  constructor(public loginService: LoginService, public router: Router) { }

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {

    const expectedRole = route.data.expectedRole;
    const userDetails = this.loginService.getUserDetails();

    if (userDetails != null) { 
      console.log('not null');

      userDetails.roles[0].forEach(e => {
        if(e.name === expectedRole){
          console.log('return true');
          return true;
        }
      });
    }

    this.router.navigate(['login']);
    console.log('return false');
    return false;
  }
}
```

When clicking on the route for a user with the expectedRole I see 
not null, return true, return false in the console..
I have canActivate returning boolean. 
Call to loginService.geUserDetails() is returning jwt deocoded so not sure why anything is happening asynchronously.

```
public getUserDetails() {
    return this.jwtHelper.decodeToken(sessionStorage.getItem('AuthToken'));
  }
```

Please help, other similar questions involve http request which I am not doing here. Hopefully something simple I am missing. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning true inside the forEach scope. You have to do it outside:

```
export class RoleGuardService implements CanActivate {

  constructor(public loginService: LoginService, public router: Router) { }

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {

    const expectedRole = route.data.expectedRole;
    const userDetails = this.loginService.getUserDetails();

    if (userDetails !== null) { 
      console.log('not null');
      if (userDetails.roles[0].some(e => e.name === expectedRole)) {
          return true;
      }
    }

    this.router.navigate(['login']);
    console.log('return false');
    return false;
  }
}
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

The javascript `array.forEach(...)` can only be stopped by throwing an exception (see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)).

If you want to stop your loop, just use a simple `for-loop`:

```
...
for(let i = 0; i < userDetails.roles[0].length; i ++) {
    let e = userDetails.roles[0][i];
    if(e.name === expectedRole){
        console.log('return true');
        return true;
    }
});
...
```